# Pytorch backward error

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Here I overcame a problem about backward, below is a simple example written by python code.

[image]

the print information is that

[image]

This really confused me as self.weights is used as a important part in my transformer_based project, while i meets this problem, i try puts self.weights into torch.nn.paramaters but failed, could somebody give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you index into a tensor, you are actually creating a new data object. The new data object has a computational graph linking it to the weights tensor via the select operation, but they are not the same thing.

```py
weights = torch.ones(3, requires_grad=True)
print(weights)
> tensor([1., 1., 1.], requires_grad=True)

print(weights[0])
> tensor(1., grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>)

print(weights.data_ptr())
> 94109293078336

print(weights[0].data_ptr())
> 94109293078336
```

When you try to access `weights[i].grad`, you should get the error:

```
UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward().
```

This is because you are trying to access the grad attribute of a different object.

To access the gradient, you need to use the leaf variable:

```py
weights = torch.ones(3, requires_grad=True)
a = 2 * weights[0]
a.backward()
print(weights.grad)
> tensor([2., 0., 0.])
```

If you want to access a slice of the gradient, you need to slice the gradient of the leaf tensor:

```py
weights = torch.ones(3, requires_grad=True)
a = 2 * weights[0]
a.backward()
print(weights.grad[0])
> tensor(2.)
```

Comment: Thanks Karl! Now i get the correct understanding of leaf variable in the computational graph